# Gunicorn Docker container only listens on `0.0.0.0`

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to set up an nginx reverse proxy to a gunicorn app server serving up my flask app. The gunicorn container listens on port 5000, and nginx listens on port 80. The problem is that I can still access the app through the browser by visiting `localhost:5000`, even though I have set gunicorn to listen to localhost of the docker container only, and all requests should pass through the nginx container to the gunicorn container through port 80. This is my set up.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - data:/home/microblog
    networks:
      - web

  web_proxy:
    container_name: web_proxy
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - data:/flask:ro
      - ./nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:

volumes:
  data:
```

Dockerfile.web

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# Environment Variables
ENV FLASK_APP=microblog.py
ENV FLASK_ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
# Don't copy .pyc files to cointainer
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Security / Permissions (1/2)
RUN adduser -D microblog
WORKDIR /home/microblog

# Virtual Environment
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -U pip
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn pymysql

# Install App
COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY microblog.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

# Security / Permissions (2/2)
RUN chown -R microblog:microblog ./
USER microblog

# Start Application
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

boot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
source venv/bin/activate
flask db upgrade
exec gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - microblog:app
```

Even though I have set `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000', in stdout of` docker-compose` I see

```
web_app_1    | [2021-03-02 22:54:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
web_app_1    | [2021-03-02 22:54:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
```

And I am still able to see the website from port 5000 in my browser. I'm not sure why it is listening on `0.0.0.0` when I have explicitly set it to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your docker-compose has

```
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
```

which tells the docker-proxy to listen on port 5000 on the host machine and forward  requests to the container. If you don't want port 5000 to be externally available, remove this.

Also, it's good that you didn't succeed in making gunicorn listen only to 127.0.0.1; if you did, the `web_proxy` container wouldn't be able to connect to it. So you may as well undo your attempt to do that.

Comment: Thank you. That totally makes sense. I just don't understand how I would make the web_app listen for connections from the web_proxy but not from requests from, say, my browser.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam containers all exist on a private network that isn't accessible from other machines. Listening on 0.0.0.0 in a container allows accepting connections from other containers on the same private network, but *not* from the outside world.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam (by default; it's possible for containers to share the host network stack, or to do other things, but that's not the usual situation).

Comment: I understand that. But then why am I able to still connect to web_app container from my web browser by pointing to `http://localhost:5000`? How can I confine web_app server to the docker private network? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam by not forwarding the port with a `ports` directive.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you! I get it now. Thank you for explaining it. I knew it was something very trivial I was overlooking!